# Converting &amp; to & in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, escaping, html-entities

I have a URL string in the following format.

> `http://myserver.com/_layouts/feed.aspx?xsl=4&amp;web=%2F&amp;page=dda3fd10-c776-4d69-8c55-2f1c74b343e2&amp;wp=476f174a-82df-4611-a3df-e13255d97533`

I want to replace **`&amp;`** with **`&`** in the above URL. My result should be:

> `http://myserver.com/_layouts/feed.aspx?xsl=4&web=%2F&page=dda3fd10-c776-4d69-8c55-2f1c74b343e2&amp;wp=476f174a-82df-4611-a3df-e13255d97533`

Can someone post me the code to get this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
```

Comment: I did the same...but is there any builtin way to do this...

Comment: @nbojja How much more built in do you want? If you're that concerned, add a method that does this as a category on NSString and then it's built in.

Comment: @Abizern: Many languages have built-in methods to encode and decode HTML entities, Obj-C lacks this and many other things programmers take for granted since 2002. Searching and replacing is a poor substitute, because you will have to spend quite some time to know you get all the entities.

Comment: @Abizern OP was likely concerned with a generalized HTML decoding solution, as just "&" is likely not the only character this may occur with.

Answer (score 114):

Check out my [NSString category for HTML](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m). Here are the methods available:

```
// Strips HTML tags & comments, removes extra whitespace and decodes HTML character entities.
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;

// Decode all HTML entities using GTM.
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;

// Encode all HTML entities using GTM.
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;

// Minimal unicode encoding will only cover characters from table
// A.2.2 of http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_Special_characters
// which is what you want for a unicode encoded webpage.
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities:(BOOL)isUnicode;

// Replace newlines with <br /> tags.
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;

// Remove newlines and white space from string.
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Michael -- very handy! (As handy as the answer to this question that got accepted is wrong!)

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall Would you mind publishing your category to CocoaPods? Would be great!

Answer (score 8):

There is no built-in function for this in the iPhone SDK. You should [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/) that you want the functionality. In the normal Mac OS X SDK you can either load the fragment into an [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/) as HTML and ask it to hand back a plain string, or use [CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities()](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFXMLTreeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities).

```
@interface NSString (LGAdditions)
- (NSString *) stringByUnescapingEntities;
@end

@implementation NSString (LGAdditions)
- (NSString *) stringByUnescapingEntities {
  CFStringRef retvalCF = CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)self, NULL);
  return [NSMakeCollectable(retvalCF) autorelease];
}
@end
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) {sigh}

Comment: @mpemburn did you try : `    CFStringRef retvalCF = CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFAllocatorRef)self, NULL);
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(retvalCF);`

Comment: It shouldn't be bridged to CFAllocatorRef, but rather CFStringRef.  That was wrong in the original code listing, too.

Answer (score 4):

For iOS the following code should work for numeric codes. It should be relatively easy to extend to the likes of `&amp;` ...

```
-(NSString*)unescapeHtmlCodes:(NSString*)input { 

NSRange rangeOfHTMLEntity = [input rangeOfString:@"&#"];
if( NSNotFound == rangeOfHTMLEntity.location ) { 
    return input;
}


NSMutableString* answer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[answer autorelease];

NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil]; // we want all white-space

while( ![scanner isAtEnd] ) { 

    NSString* fragment;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"&#" intoString:&fragment];
    if( nil != fragment ) { // e.g. '&#38; B'
        [answer appendString:fragment];        
    }

    if( ![scanner isAtEnd] ) { // implicitly we scanned to the next '&#'

        int scanLocation = (int)[scanner scanLocation];
        [scanner setScanLocation:scanLocation+2]; // skip over '&#'

        int htmlCode;
        if( [scanner scanInt:&htmlCode] ) {
            char c = htmlCode;
            [answer appendFormat:@"%c", c];

            scanLocation = (int)[scanner scanLocation];
            [scanner setScanLocation:scanLocation+1]; // skip over ';'

        } else {
            // err ? 
        }
    }

}

return answer;

}
```

Some unit-test code ...

```
-(void)testUnescapeHtmlCodes {

NSString* expected = @"A & B";
NSString* actual = [self unescapeHtmlCodes:@"A &#38; B"];
STAssertTrue( [expected isEqualToString:actual], @"actual = %@", actual );

expected = @"& B";
actual = [self unescapeHtmlCodes:@"&#38; B"];    
STAssertTrue( [expected isEqualToString:actual], @"actual = %@", actual );

expected = @"A &";
actual = [self unescapeHtmlCodes:@"A &#38;"];
STAssertTrue( [expected isEqualToString:actual], @"actual = %@", actual );

}
```