# HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

First of all, I found this: [[Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape), but it doesn't work for me.

My encoded characters (come from a RSS feed, btw) look like this: `&#038;`

I searched all over the net and found related discussions, but no fix for my particular encoding, I think they are called hexadecimal characters.

Comment: This comment is six months after the original question, so it's more for those that stumble across this question looking for an answer and a solution.  A very similar question came up just recently that I answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254862/special-characters-in-nsstring-from-html/2260140#2260140  It uses RegexKitLite and Blocks to do a search and replace of the `&#...;` in a string with its equivalent character.

Comment: What specifically “doesn't work”? I don't see anything in this question that isn't a duplicate of that earlier question.

Comment: It's decimal. Hexadecimal is `&#x038;`.

Comment: The difference between decimal and hexadecimal being that decimal is base-10, whereas hexadecimal is base-16. “38” is a different number in each base; in base 10, it's 3×10 + 8×1 = thirty-eight, whereas in base-16, it's 3×16 + 8×1 = fifty-six. Higher digits are (multiples of) higher powers of the base; the lowest whole digit is base**0 (= 1), the next higher digit is base**1 (= base), the next one is base**2 (= base * base), etc. This is exponentation at work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Those are called [Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference).  When they take the form of `&#<number>;` they are called *numeric entity references*.  Basically, it's a string representation of the byte that should be substituted.  In the case of `&#038;`, it represents the character with the value of 38 in the ISO-8859-1 character encoding scheme, which is `&`.

The reason the ampersand has to be encoded in RSS is it's a reserved special character.

What you need to do is parse the string and replace the entities with a byte matching the value between `&#` and `;`.  I don't know of any great ways to do this in objective C, but [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067652/converting-to-in-objective-c) might be of some help.

Edit: Since answering this some two years ago there are some great solutions; see @Michael Waterfall's answer below.

Comment: +1 I was just about to submit the exact same answer (including the same links, no less!)

Comment: “Basically, it's a string representation of the byte that should be substituted.” More like character. This is text, not data; upon converting the text to data, the character may occupy multiple bytes, depending on the character and the encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You said "it represents the character with the value of 38 in the ISO-8859-1 character encoding scheme, which is &". Are you sure about that? Do you have a link to a character table of this type? Because from what I recall that was a single quote.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#ISO-8859-1 or just type &#038; into google.

Comment: and what about &amp; or &copy; symbols?

Answer (score 164):

Check out my [NSString category for HTML](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m). Here are the methods available:

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```

Comment: Dude, excellent functions. Your stringByDecodingXMLEntities method made my day!  Thanks!

Comment: No problem ;) Glad you found it useful!

Comment: This is amazing. stringByDecodingXMLEntities is a real timesaver. Thanks!

Comment: After a few hours searching I know that this is the only way to do it that really works. NSString is overdue for a string method that can do this. Well done.

Comment: I found (2) on Michael's license too restrictive for my use case, so I used Nikita's solution. Including three Apache-2.0-licensed files from google toolbox works great for me.

Comment: Wait... there isn't any "stringByDecodingXMLEntities" like these folks are talking about. What gives??

Comment: @Cyprus106 It's been replaced by `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities`

Comment: Code update for ARC would be handy.. Xcode is throwing ton of ARC errors and warnings on build

Comment: You are a saint. stringByDecodingHTMLEntities did just what I've been looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, NSDate from Internet date is great too!

Comment: &#10 for new line is not added. any reason why? thanks a lot btw. great job.

Comment: Regarding this code if people need ARC, you can just add this compile flag on the specific files : "-fno-objc-arc"
It allow you to have this part of code w/o it on your project that use it :)

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall: Excellent. But using `stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText` also removes newline character. I tried to comment some code in that function but it causes crashes. Any suggestions?

Comment: To strip html tags, use method stringByStrippingTags

Answer (score 53):

The one by Daniel is basically very nice, and I fixed a few issues there:

1. removed the skipping character for NSSCanner (otherwise spaces between two continuous entities would be ignored

   [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
2. fixed the parsing when there are isolated '&' symbols (I am not sure what is the 'correct' output for this, I just compared it against firefox):

e.g.

```
    &#ABC DF & B&#39;  & C&#39; Items (288)
```

here is the modified code:

```
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingXMLEntities {
    NSUInteger myLength = [self length];
    NSUInteger ampIndex = [self rangeOfString:@"&" options:NSLiteralSearch].location;

    // Short-circuit if there are no ampersands.
    if (ampIndex == NSNotFound) {
        return self;
    }
    // Make result string with some extra capacity.
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(myLength * 1.25)];

    // First iteration doesn't need to scan to & since we did that already, but for code simplicity's sake we'll do it again with the scanner.
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];

    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

    NSCharacterSet *boundaryCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \t\n\r;"];

    do {
        // Scan up to the next entity or the end of the string.
        NSString *nonEntityString;
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:&nonEntityString]) {
            [result appendString:nonEntityString];
        }
        if ([scanner isAtEnd]) {
            goto finish;
        }
        // Scan either a HTML or numeric character entity reference.
        if ([scanner scanString:@"&amp;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"&"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&apos;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"'"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&quot;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"\""];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&lt;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"<"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&gt;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@">"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&#" intoString:NULL]) {
            BOOL gotNumber;
            unsigned charCode;
            NSString *xForHex = @"";

            // Is it hex or decimal?
            if ([scanner scanString:@"x" intoString:&xForHex]) {
                gotNumber = [scanner scanHexInt:&charCode];
            }
            else {
                gotNumber = [scanner scanInt:(int*)&charCode];
            }

            if (gotNumber) {
                [result appendFormat:@"%C", (unichar)charCode];

                [scanner scanString:@";" intoString:NULL];
            }
            else {
                NSString *unknownEntity = @"";

                [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:boundaryCharacterSet intoString:&unknownEntity];


                [result appendFormat:@"&#%@%@", xForHex, unknownEntity];

                //[scanner scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&unknownEntity];
                //[result appendFormat:@"&#%@%@;", xForHex, unknownEntity];
                NSLog(@"Expected numeric character entity but got &#%@%@;", xForHex, unknownEntity);

            }

        }
        else {
            NSString *amp;

            [scanner scanString:@"&" intoString:&amp];  //an isolated & symbol
            [result appendString:amp];

            /*
            NSString *unknownEntity = @"";
            [scanner scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&unknownEntity];
            NSString *semicolon = @"";
            [scanner scanString:@";" intoString:&semicolon];
            [result appendFormat:@"%@%@", unknownEntity, semicolon];
            NSLog(@"Unsupported XML character entity %@%@", unknownEntity, semicolon);
             */
        }

    }
    while (![scanner isAtEnd]);

finish:
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This should be the definite answer to the question!! Thanks!

Comment: This worked great. Unfortunately the highest rated answer's code doesn't work anymore due to ARC issues, but this does.

Comment: @TedKulp it works just fine, you just need to disable ARC per file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: I would thumbs you up twice if I could.

Comment: Swift translation for people still visiting this question in 2016+ : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35303635/1153630

Answer (score 49):

As of iOS 7, you can decode HTML characters natively by using an `NSAttributedString` with the `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` attribute:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"&#63743; &amp; &#38; &lt; &gt; &trade; &copy; &hearts; &clubs; &spades; &diams;";
NSData *stringData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
NSAttributedString *decodedString;
decodedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData
                                                 options:options
                                      documentAttributes:NULL
                                                   error:NULL];
```

The decoded attributed string will now be displayed as:  & & < > ™ © ♥ ♣ ♠ ♦.

**Note:** This will only work if called on the main thread.

Comment: best answer if you don't need to support iOS 6 and older

Comment: no, not the best if someone wants to encode it on bg thread ;O

Comment: This worked for decoding an entity, but it also messed up a non-encoded dash.

Comment: This is forced to happen on the main thread. So you probably don't want to do this if you don't have to.

Comment: It just hangs the GUI when it's matter of UITableView. Hence, not working correctly.

Comment: Great solution. Unfortunately, non-encoded dashes causes problems. This is what I did prior the decoding code:

`string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"–" withString:@"&ndash;"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"—" withString:@"&mdash;"];`

Please let me know if any other characters causes problems as well???

Comment: nice concise solution. when i return decodedString i return the [decodedString string] instead to return NSString instead of NSAttributedString

Comment: Nice solution, note though that it is pretty _invasive_, i.e. it reduces multiple consecutive spaces into one. That might not be intended if all you want to do is decoding HTML entities.

Answer (score 35):

Nobody seems to mention one of the simplest options: [Google Toolbox for Mac](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/)
(Despite the name, this works on iOS too.)

https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/blob/master/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.h

```
/// Get a string where internal characters that are escaped for HTML are unescaped 
//
///  For example, '&amp;' becomes '&'
///  Handles &#32; and &#x32; cases as well
///
//  Returns:
//    Autoreleased NSString
//
- (NSString *)gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML;
```

And I had to include only three files in the project: header, implementation and `GTMDefines.h`.

Comment: I have included this three scripts, but how can I use it now?

Comment: @borut-t [myString gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML]

Comment: I chose to only include those three files, so I needed to do this to make it compatible with arc: http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/ARC_Compatibility

Comment: i have to say this is the simplest and most lightweight solution by far

Comment: I wish I could get this to work completely. It seems to skip over many of them in my strings.

Comment: @JosephToronto Perhaps, post a sample string here and how you expect it to be escaped?

Comment: I had a lot o Polish and Hungarian encoded chars and this function saved my day! Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I ought to post this on GitHub or something.  This goes in a category of NSString, uses `NSScanner` for the implementation, and handles both hex and decimal numeric character entities as well as the usual symbolic ones.

Also, it handles malformed strings (when you have an & followed by an invalid sequence of characters) relatively gracefully, which turned out to be crucial in my [released app](http://danieldickison.com/etsyaddict/) that uses this code.

```
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingXMLEntities {
    NSUInteger myLength = [self length];
    NSUInteger ampIndex = [self rangeOfString:@"&" options:NSLiteralSearch].location;

    // Short-circuit if there are no ampersands.
    if (ampIndex == NSNotFound) {
        return self;
    }
    // Make result string with some extra capacity.
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(myLength * 1.25)];

    // First iteration doesn't need to scan to & since we did that already, but for code simplicity's sake we'll do it again with the scanner.
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];
    do {
        // Scan up to the next entity or the end of the string.
        NSString *nonEntityString;
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:&nonEntityString]) {
            [result appendString:nonEntityString];
        }
        if ([scanner isAtEnd]) {
            goto finish;
        }
        // Scan either a HTML or numeric character entity reference.
        if ([scanner scanString:@"&amp;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"&"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&apos;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"'"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&quot;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"\""];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&lt;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@"<"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&gt;" intoString:NULL])
            [result appendString:@">"];
        else if ([scanner scanString:@"&#" intoString:NULL]) {
            BOOL gotNumber;
            unsigned charCode;
            NSString *xForHex = @"";

            // Is it hex or decimal?
            if ([scanner scanString:@"x" intoString:&xForHex]) {
                gotNumber = [scanner scanHexInt:&charCode];
            }
            else {
                gotNumber = [scanner scanInt:(int*)&charCode];
            }
            if (gotNumber) {
                [result appendFormat:@"%C", charCode];
            }
            else {
                NSString *unknownEntity = @"";
                [scanner scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&unknownEntity];
                [result appendFormat:@"&#%@%@;", xForHex, unknownEntity];
                NSLog(@"Expected numeric character entity but got &#%@%@;", xForHex, unknownEntity);
            }
            [scanner scanString:@";" intoString:NULL];
        }
        else {
            NSString *unknownEntity = @"";
            [scanner scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&unknownEntity];
            NSString *semicolon = @"";
            [scanner scanString:@";" intoString:&semicolon];
            [result appendFormat:@"%@%@", unknownEntity, semicolon];
            NSLog(@"Unsupported XML character entity %@%@", unknownEntity, semicolon);
        }
    }
    while (![scanner isAtEnd]);

finish:
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Very useful piece of code, however it does have a couple of issues that were addressed by Walty. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: do you know a way to show lambda, mu, nu, pi symbols by decoding their XML entities like &micro; ... ect ????

Comment: You should avoid using `goto`s as its terrible code style. You should replace the line `goto finish;` with `break;`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way I do it using [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) framework:

```
-(NSString*) decodeHtmlUnicodeCharacters: (NSString*) html {
NSString* result = [html copy];
NSArray* matches = [result arrayOfCaptureComponentsMatchedByRegex: @"\\&#([\\d]+);"];

if (![matches count]) 
    return result;

for (int i=0; i<[matches count]; i++) {
    NSArray* array = [matches objectAtIndex: i];
    NSString* charCode = [array objectAtIndex: 1];
    int code = [charCode intValue];
    NSString* character = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", code];
    result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: [array objectAtIndex: 0]
                                               withString: character];      
}   
return result;
```

}

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

you can use just this function to solve this problem.

```
+ (NSString*) decodeHtmlUnicodeCharactersToString:(NSString*)str
{
    NSMutableString* string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:str];  // #&39; replace with '
    NSString* unicodeStr = nil;
    NSString* replaceStr = nil;
    int counter = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < [string length]; ++i)
    {
        unichar char1 = [string characterAtIndex:i];    
        for (int k = i + 1; k < [string length] - 1; ++k)
        {
            unichar char2 = [string characterAtIndex:k];    

            if (char1 == '&'  && char2 == '#' ) 
            {   
                ++counter;
                unicodeStr = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i + 2 , 2)];    
                // read integer value i.e, 39
                replaceStr = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange (i, 5)];     //     #&39;
                [string replaceCharactersInRange: [string rangeOfString:replaceStr] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[unicodeStr intValue]]];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [string autorelease];

    if (counter > 1)
        return  [self decodeHtmlUnicodeCharactersToString:string]; 
    else
        return string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Swift version of [Walty Yeung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453142/1153630):

```
extension String {
    static private let mappings = ["&quot;" : "\"","&amp;" : "&", "&lt;" : "<", "&gt;" : ">","&nbsp;" : " ","&iexcl;" : "¡","&cent;" : "¢","&pound;" : " £","&curren;" : "¤","&yen;" : "¥","&brvbar;" : "¦","&sect;" : "§","&uml;" : "¨","&copy;" : "©","&ordf;" : " ª","&laquo" : "«","&not" : "¬","&reg" : "®","&macr" : "¯","&deg" : "°","&plusmn" : "±","&sup2; " : "²","&sup3" : "³","&acute" : "´","&micro" : "µ","&para" : "¶","&middot" : "·","&cedil" : "¸","&sup1" : "¹","&ordm" : "º","&raquo" : "»&","frac14" : "¼","&frac12" : "½","&frac34" : "¾","&iquest" : "¿","&times" : "×","&divide" : "÷","&ETH" : "Ð","&eth" : "ð","&THORN" : "Þ","&thorn" : "þ","&AElig" : "Æ","&aelig" : "æ","&OElig" : "Œ","&oelig" : "œ","&Aring" : "Å","&Oslash" : "Ø","&Ccedil" : "Ç","&ccedil" : "ç","&szlig" : "ß","&Ntilde;" : "Ñ","&ntilde;":"ñ",]

    func stringByDecodingXMLEntities() -> String {

        guard let _ = self.rangeOfString("&", options: [.LiteralSearch]) else {
            return self
        }

        var result = ""

        let scanner = NSScanner(string: self)
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil

        let boundaryCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " \t\n\r;")

        repeat {
            var nonEntityString: NSString? = nil

            if scanner.scanUpToString("&", intoString: &nonEntityString) {
                if let s = nonEntityString as? String {
                    result.appendContentsOf(s)
                }
            }

            if scanner.atEnd {
                break
            }

            var didBreak = false
            for (k,v) in String.mappings {
                if scanner.scanString(k, intoString: nil) {
                    result.appendContentsOf(v)
                    didBreak = true
                    break
                }
            }

            if !didBreak {

                if scanner.scanString("&#", intoString: nil) {

                    var gotNumber = false
                    var charCodeUInt: UInt32 = 0
                    var charCodeInt: Int32 = -1
                    var xForHex: NSString? = nil

                    if scanner.scanString("x", intoString: &xForHex) {
                        gotNumber = scanner.scanHexInt(&charCodeUInt)
                    }
                    else {
                        gotNumber = scanner.scanInt(&charCodeInt)
                    }

                    if gotNumber {
                        let newChar = String(format: "%C", (charCodeInt > -1) ? charCodeInt : charCodeUInt)
                        result.appendContentsOf(newChar)
                        scanner.scanString(";", intoString: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        var unknownEntity: NSString? = nil
                        scanner.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(boundaryCharacterSet, intoString: &unknownEntity)
                        let h = xForHex ?? ""
                        let u = unknownEntity ?? ""
                        result.appendContentsOf("&#\(h)\(u)")
                    }
                }
                else {
                    scanner.scanString("&", intoString: nil)
                    result.appendContentsOf("&")
                }
            }

        } while (!scanner.atEnd)

        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the great MWFeedParser framework of Michael Waterfall (referred to his answer) has been forked by rmchaara who has update it with ARC support!

You can find it in Github [here](https://github.com/rmchaara/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/MWFeedParser.h)

It really works great, I used stringByDecodingHTMLEntities method and works flawlessly.

Comment: That fixes the ARC issues - but introduces some warnings. I think it's safe to ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

As if you need another solution!  This one is pretty simple and quite effective:

```
@interface NSString (NSStringCategory)
- (NSString *) stringByReplacingISO8859Codes;
@end


@implementation NSString (NSStringCategory)
- (NSString *) stringByReplacingISO8859Codes
{
    NSString *dataString = self;
    do {
        //*** See if string contains &# prefix
        NSRange range = [dataString rangeOfString: @"&#" options: NSRegularExpressionSearch];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
            break;
        }
        //*** Get the next three charaters after the prefix
        NSString *isoHex = [dataString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(range.location + 2, 3)];
        //*** Create the full code for replacement
        NSString *isoString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"&#%@;", isoHex];
        //*** Convert to decimal integer
        unsigned decimal = 0;
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%@", isoHex]];
        [scanner scanHexInt: &decimal];
        //*** Use decimal code to get unicode character
        NSString *unicode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", decimal];
        //*** Replace all occurences of this code in the string
        dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: isoString withString: unicode];
    } while (TRUE); //*** Loop until we hit the NSNotFound

    return dataString;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Character Entity Reference as a string, e.g. `@"2318"`, you can extract a recoded NSString with the correct unicode character using `strtoul`;

```
NSString *unicodePoint = @"2318"
unichar iconChar = (unichar) strtoul(unicodePoint.UTF8String, NULL, 16);
NSString *recoded = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", iconChar];
NSLog(@"recoded: %@", recoded");
// prints out "recoded: ⌘"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 version of Jugale's answer**

```
extension String {
    static private let mappings = ["&quot;" : "\"","&amp;" : "&", "&lt;" : "<", "&gt;" : ">","&nbsp;" : " ","&iexcl;" : "¡","&cent;" : "¢","&pound;" : " £","&curren;" : "¤","&yen;" : "¥","&brvbar;" : "¦","&sect;" : "§","&uml;" : "¨","&copy;" : "©","&ordf;" : " ª","&laquo" : "«","&not" : "¬","&reg" : "®","&macr" : "¯","&deg" : "°","&plusmn" : "±","&sup2; " : "²","&sup3" : "³","&acute" : "´","&micro" : "µ","&para" : "¶","&middot" : "·","&cedil" : "¸","&sup1" : "¹","&ordm" : "º","&raquo" : "»&","frac14" : "¼","&frac12" : "½","&frac34" : "¾","&iquest" : "¿","&times" : "×","&divide" : "÷","&ETH" : "Ð","&eth" : "ð","&THORN" : "Þ","&thorn" : "þ","&AElig" : "Æ","&aelig" : "æ","&OElig" : "Œ","&oelig" : "œ","&Aring" : "Å","&Oslash" : "Ø","&Ccedil" : "Ç","&ccedil" : "ç","&szlig" : "ß","&Ntilde;" : "Ñ","&ntilde;":"ñ",]

    func stringByDecodingXMLEntities() -> String {

        guard let _ = self.range(of: "&", options: [.literal]) else {
            return self
        }

        var result = ""

        let scanner = Scanner(string: self)
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil

        let boundaryCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: " \t\n\r;")

        repeat {
            var nonEntityString: NSString? = nil

            if scanner.scanUpTo("&", into: &nonEntityString) {
                if let s = nonEntityString as? String {
                    result.append(s)
                }
            }

            if scanner.isAtEnd {
                break
            }

            var didBreak = false
            for (k,v) in String.mappings {
                if scanner.scanString(k, into: nil) {
                    result.append(v)
                    didBreak = true
                    break
                }
            }

            if !didBreak {

                if scanner.scanString("&#", into: nil) {

                    var gotNumber = false
                    var charCodeUInt: UInt32 = 0
                    var charCodeInt: Int32 = -1
                    var xForHex: NSString? = nil

                    if scanner.scanString("x", into: &xForHex) {
                        gotNumber = scanner.scanHexInt32(&charCodeUInt)
                    }
                    else {
                        gotNumber = scanner.scanInt32(&charCodeInt)
                    }

                    if gotNumber {
                        let newChar = String(format: "%C", (charCodeInt > -1) ? charCodeInt : charCodeUInt)
                        result.append(newChar)
                        scanner.scanString(";", into: nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        var unknownEntity: NSString? = nil
                        scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: boundaryCharacterSet, into: &unknownEntity)
                        let h = xForHex ?? ""
                        let u = unknownEntity ?? ""
                        result.append("&#\(h)\(u)")
                    }
                }
                else {
                    scanner.scanString("&", into: nil)
                    result.append("&")
                }
            }

        } while (!scanner.isAtEnd)

        return result
    }
}
```