# Special Characters in NSString from HTML

Tags: iphone, xml, nsstring

I'm fetching data from an XML source and parsing through it with tbxml. Everything is working fine until I get to a latin letter like the "é" it will display as:
Code:

```
&#233;
```

I don't see a proper method of NSString to do the conversion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a pretty common problem.  Check out [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa)

Comment: Thanks! I searched for this here, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex.  A regex is a solution to, and cause of, all problems! :)

The example below uses, at least as of this writing, the unreleased RegexKitLite 4.0.  You can get the 4.0 development snapshot via svn:

`shell% svn co http://regexkit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/regexkit regexkit`

The examples below take advantage of the new 4.0 Blocks feature to do a search and replace of the `&#233;` character entities.

This first example is the "simpler" of the two.  It **only** handles decimal character entities like `&#233;` and not hexadecimal character entities like `&#xe9;`.  If you can guarantee that you'll never have hexadecimal character entities, this should be fine:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RegexKitLite.h"

int main(int argc, char *charv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSString *string = @"A test: &#233; and &#xe9; ? YAY! Even >0xffff are handled: &#119808; or &#x1D400;, see? (0x1d400 == MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL A)";
  NSString *regex = @"&#([0-9]+);";

  NSString *replacedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regex usingBlock:^NSString *(NSInteger captureCount, NSString * const capturedStrings[captureCount], const NSRange capturedRanges[captureCount], volatile BOOL * const stop) {
      NSUInteger u16Length = 0UL, u32_ch = [capturedStrings[1] integerValue];
      UniChar u16Buffer[3];

      if (u32_ch <= 0xFFFFU)       { u16Buffer[u16Length++] = ((u32_ch >= 0xD800U) && (u32_ch <= 0xDFFFU)) ? 0xFFFDU : u32_ch; }
      else if (u32_ch > 0x10FFFFU) { u16Buffer[u16Length++] = 0xFFFDU; }
      else                         { u32_ch -= 0x0010000UL; u16Buffer[u16Length++] = ((u32_ch >> 10) + 0xD800U); u16Buffer[u16Length++] = ((u32_ch & 0x3FFUL) + 0xDC00U); }

      return([NSString stringWithCharacters:u16Buffer length:u16Length]);
    }];

  NSLog(@"replaced: '%@'", replacedString);

  return(0);
}
```

Compile and run with:

```
shell% gcc -arch i386 -g -o charReplace charReplace.m RegexKitLite.m -framework Foundation -licucore
shell% ./charReplace
2010-02-13 22:51:48.909 charReplace[35527:903] replaced: 'A test: é and &#xe9; ? YAY! Even >0xffff are handled:  or &#x1D400;, see? (0x1d400 == MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL A)'
```

The 0x1d4000 character might not show up in your browser, but it looks like a bold A in a terminal window.

The "three lines" in the middle of the replacement block ensure correct conversion of `UTF-32` characters that are > `0xFFFF`.  I put this in for completeness and correctness sake. Invalid `UTF-32` character values (`0xd800` - `0xdfff`) are turned in to `U+FFFD`, or `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`. If you can "guarantee" that you'll never have `&#...;` character entities that are > `0xFFFF` (or `65535`), and are always "legal" `UTF-32`, then you can remove those lines and simplify the whole block down to something like:

```
return([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [capturedStrings[1] integerValue]]);
```

The second example does both decimal and hexadecimal character entities:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RegexKitLite.h"

int main(int argc, char *charv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSString *string = @"A test: &#233; and &#xe9; ? YAY! Even >0xffff are handled: &#119808; or &#x1D400;, see? (0x1d400 == MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL A)";
  NSString *regex = @"&#(?:([0-9]+)|x([0-9a-fA-F]+));";

  NSString *replacedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regex usingBlock:^NSString *(NSInteger captureCount, NSString * const capturedStrings[captureCount], const NSRange capturedRanges[captureCount], volatile BOOL * const stop) {
      NSUInteger u16Length = 0UL, u32_ch = 0UL;
      UniChar u16Buffer[3];

      CFStringRef cfSelf = (capturedRanges[1].location != NSNotFound) ? (CFStringRef)capturedStrings[1] : (CFStringRef)capturedStrings[2];
      UInt8 buffer[64];
      const char *cptr;

      if((cptr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(cfSelf, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman)) == NULL) {
        CFRange range     = CFRangeMake(0L, CFStringGetLength(cfSelf));
        CFIndex usedBytes = 0L;
        CFStringGetBytes(cfSelf, range, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, '?', false, buffer, 60L, &usedBytes);
        buffer[usedBytes] = 0;
        cptr              = (const char *)buffer;
      }

      u32_ch = strtoul(cptr, NULL, (capturedRanges[1].location != NSNotFound) ? 10 : 16);

      if (u32_ch <= 0xFFFFU)       { u16Buffer[u16Length++] = ((u32_ch >= 0xD800U) && (u32_ch <= 0xDFFFU)) ? 0xFFFDU : u32_ch; }
      else if (u32_ch > 0x10FFFFU) { u16Buffer[u16Length++] = 0xFFFDU; }
      else                         { u32_ch -= 0x0010000UL; u16Buffer[u16Length++] = ((u32_ch >> 10) + 0xD800U); u16Buffer[u16Length++] = ((u32_ch & 0x3FFUL) + 0xDC00U); }

      return([NSString stringWithCharacters:u16Buffer length:u16Length]);
    }];

  NSLog(@"replaced: '%@'", replacedString);

  return(0);
}
```

Again, compile and run with:

```
shell% gcc -arch i386 -g -o charReplace charReplace.m RegexKitLite.m -framework Foundation -licucore
shell% ./charReplace
2010-02-13 22:52:02.182 charReplace[35540:903] replaced: 'A test: é and é ? YAY! Even >0xffff are handled:  or , see? (0x1d400 == MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL A)'
```

Note the difference in the output compared to the first: The first still had `&#xe9;` in it, and in this one it is replaced.  Again, it's a tad longish, but I choose to go for completeness and correctness.

Both examples can have the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:` method replaced with the following for "extra speed", but you should refer to the documentation to see the caveats of using `RKLRegexEnumerationFastCapturedStringsXXX`.  It's important to note that using it in the above is not a problem and perfectly safe (and one of the reasons why I added the option to RegexKitLite).

```
  NSString *replacedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regex options:RKLNoOptions inRange:NSMakeRange(0UL, [string length]) error:NULL enumerationOptions:RKLRegexEnumerationFastCapturedStringsXXX usingBlock:^NSString *(NSInteger captureCount, NSString * const capturedStrings[captureCount], const NSRange capturedRanges[captureCount], volatile BOOL * const stop) {
```

Another answer to your question pointed you to [this Stack Overflow Question with an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa).  Differences between this solution and that solution (based on nothing more than a quick once over):

This solution:

- Requires an external library (RegexKitLite).
- Uses Blocks to perform its work, which is not available "everywhere" yet.  Though there is [Plausible Blocks](http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/), which lets you use Blocks on Mac OS X 10.5 and IPhone OS 2.2+ (I think).  They backported the 10.6 gcc Blocks changes and made them available.

The other solution:

- Uses standard Foundation classes, works everywhere.
- A little less correct in handling some `UTF-32` character code points (probably not an issue in practice).
- Handles a couple of common named character entities like `&gt;`.  This can be added easily to the above, though.

I haven't benchmarked either solution, but I'd be willing to bet large sums of money that the RegexKitLite solution using `RKLRegexEnumerationFastCapturedStringsXXX` beats the pants off the `NSScanner` solution.

And if you really wanted to add named character entities, you could change the regex to something like:

```
NSString *regex = @"&(?:#(?:([0-9]+)|x([0-9a-fA-F]+))|([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+));";
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the above at all.

Capture #3 should contain "the character entity name", which you can then use to do a look up.  A really fancy way to do this would be to have a `NSDictionary` that contains a named character as the `key` and a `NSString` `object` containing the character that that name maps to.  You could even keep the whole thing as an external `.plist` resource and lazily load it on demand with something like:

```
NSDictionary *namedCharactersDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"namedCharacters.plist"];
```

You'd obviously tweak it to use `NSBundle` to get a path to your apps resource directory, but you get this idea.  Then you'd add another condition check in the Block:

```
if(capturedRanges[3].location != NSNotFound) {
  NSString *namedCharacter = [namedCharactersDictionary objectForKey:capturedStrings[3]];
  return((namedCharacter == NULL) ? capturedStrings[0] : namedCharacter);
}
```

If the named character is in the dictionary, it will replace it.  Otherwise it returns the full `&notfound;` matched text (i.e., "does nothing").