# is it possible to decode special HTML entities in Objective C (for iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, htmlspecialchars

could you show me algorithm for implement decode special HTML entities in Objective C?
any idea?

Comment: Already asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364797/objective-c-how-to-replace-html-entities.

Answer (score 3):

Check out my [NSString category for HTML](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m). Here are the methods available:

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```

Comment: Great. Are you planning an ARC version?