# NSString convert utf8

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, encoding

I have strings that I download from the web that look like this:

```
&#x5DE;&#x5E9;&#x5D4; &#x5E4;&#x5E8;&#x5E5;
```

How can I get the real string from this string?

Comment: yes it convert from NSData but it won't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are getting from the web contains HTML entities (i.e: `&#x5DE;`).  You could manually detect and capture the hexadecimal values (ie: `0x5DE` in this case) and feed it to a NSMutableString.

This other question might have other useful options for you: [Objective-C: How to replace HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364797)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the **GTMNSString+HTML** class developed by Google. Specifically, the method:

```
/// Get a string where internal characters that are escaped for HTML are unescaped 
//
///  For example, '&amp;' becomes '&'
///  Handles &#32; and &#x32; cases as well
///
//  Returns:
//    Autoreleased NSString
//
- (NSString *)gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML;
```

[Github](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/tree/master/Classes) (Michael Waterfall) - actually from [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://google-toolbox-for-mac.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h) - may or may not be compatible with iOS.