# How can I display text from mysql in my app?

Tags: objective-c, textview, uitextview

This is how my data looks like in my database:

```
Baseball cap by adidas Originals 
-   Made from cotton
-   Embroidered brand logo to the front
-   Five panel styling
-   Ventilation holes to the side
```

If I want to render this in a `UITextView` in my app. How can I do this? Is there a way that I can render this in UITextView and the spaces and indents of the text are still there?

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice, especially when you got some excellent answers the first time around.

Comment: @CodaFi It is not the same question. The first on I asked was about a data type. This one is about how I can render in my iPhone application. Please read my question clearly before judging.

Comment: //What data type do I need to use so when I want to use this data it still contain the spaces and indents?//  and //Is there a way that I can render this in UITextView and the spaces and indents of the text are still there?// seem pretty darn close to me

Comment: @CodaFi Rendering it in xcode uses objective-c programming. data type is about mysql? Do you even know how to code? How is this similar?

Comment: No need to get offensive, mate.  It's funny, I had an answer I was thinking about posting, which works, but I see I'm not wanted here.

Comment: @TyTanLee If he didn't know programming, he could hardly have 10k+ reputation on StackOverflow. Keep your mouth closed. (Oh, and btw this is unrelated to Xcode...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this page [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m)

Source: [Objective-C: How to replace HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364797/objective-c-how-to-replace-html-entities)

Comment: @Ty Tan Lee If some answer helps you you should accept that by clicking on the tick mark next to answer.