# Decoding &#8216; in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ascii

Im saving data from a WebService and some of the info has ASCII caracters like `&#8216;` or `#038;`
At the begining I thought that setting a string with a text containing caracacters like those would work perfectly since there are other, like accents `\u00f3`, that appear decoded in the UILabels but those 2 for example don't.

Why is this? Am I understanding correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Escapes like `\u00f3` in string literals are evaluated at compile-time. If you have runtime data that has these escapes, they will not be interpreted. And `&#8216;` isn't even a string escape; it's an HTML entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Replacing HTML entities

Since you are saving data from a WebService, you can use this [NSString category for HTML](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/uiwebview-must-die/) as described in this post: [Objective-C: How to replace HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364797/objective-c-how-to-replace-html-entities)

(Html entities are stuff like: `&#8216;` - More on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references))

> The methods available in the category are:

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```

### **Response to comments**

**[NSAttributedString initWithHTML: documentAttributes:]**

*Initializes and returns a new NSAttributedString object from HTML contained in the given data object.*

```
NSData* htmlData = [yourHTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSAttributedString* theAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:htmlData documentAttributes:NULL];
```

I use this all the time and it works perfectly. I even made a macro out of it:

```
#define html2AttributedString(htmlString)                                                                   \
    [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:[(htmlString) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]         \
    documentAttributes:NULL] autorelease]
```

Usage:

```
NSAttributedString* attributedString = html2AttributedString(yourNSString);
```

And then, you can make macro for color, alignment, font, etc…

For iOS, you can check out [this page](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/uiwebview-must-die/) in which they give you a replacement.

> Our initWithHTML methods aim to perfectly match the output from the
>   Mac version. This is possible to achieve for characters and I have
>   unit tests in place that make certain this keeps being perfect.
>   Regarding the attributes there are many things that have to be done
>   slightly different on iOS to achieve the same look. I won’t bother you
>   with the details there.

Comment: I'm not questioning the validity of `-stringByDecodingHTMLEntities`, but for `-stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText`, can't you just create an `NSAttributedString` from HTML and take its string value instead?

Comment: @zneak I was just quoting the author of the category, listing the available methods. But, yes, NSAttributedString has a great method `initWithHTML: dataUsingEncoding:` that can be used to build an attributed string from HTML code. The entities will indeed be interpreted, as well as the markup (that's why I didn't suggest it). Seems like the OP only wants to get rid of the html entities.

Comment: Could you explain more on that? I actully will need to parse any kind of HTML, I just realised that WS has some html tags.
Thanks!

Comment: @DavidShaikh Done. I added more informations about **NSAttributedString initWithHTML: documentAttributes:]**. Please, note that there is a mistake in my comment above: it's not *`initWithHTML: dataUsingEncoding:`* but *`initWithHTML: documentAttributes:`* of course.

Comment: @DavidShaikh No, but there is an other way. I updated my answer accordingly. Hope this helps.