# Remove encoding from NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS application. I am receiving json from a webservice and parse it into different NSStrings. The problem is sometimes the strings include special characters that have not been decoded.

For example I could get: `Test One&quot;Two` as the NSString.

How do I remove special characters like this one from an NSString?

Comment: Are those HTML escapes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: How to replace HTML entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364797/objective-c-how-to-replace-html-entities) and/or [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Comment: I think this answer might solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/2843454/778552

Comment: Try this i hope this will help you to solve your issue....

    NSString *book=@"Test One&quot;Two";
    
    book=[book stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/99ihm91gl9j428k/X3DOjolAte

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this class awhile back to assist with stripping HTML from NSString.

**NSString+StripHTML**

NSString+StripHTML.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (StripHTML)

-(NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML;

@end
```

NSString+StripHTML.m

```
#import "NSString+StripHTML.h"

@implementation NSString (StripHTML)

-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML {
    NSRange r;
    NSString *s = [self copy];
    while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    return s;
}
```

@end

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is not quite what I'm looking for. The string is not actually in HTML format. Just has the random codes in it. Also I don't want to remove it, just properly represent it

Answer (score 0):

I think  you want just a simple Regex replacement:

This is what Neevik showed in [Use regular expression to find/replace substring in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661690/user-regular-expression-to-find-replace-substring-in-nsstring)

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"&[^;]*;" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

That should remove your special characters.

Comment: From his comment from the other answer: "I don't want to remove it, just properly represent it." Also, your regex is too hungry: @"Roger & Ebert think &quot;The Shining!&quot; was great.". I might suggest `@"&#?[a-z0-9]+;"` for the pattern and use case insensitive search. That gets you closer while still being pretty simple.