# Encoded characters in NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm using the TBXML framework to parse some XML, but am having problems with the returned string values. The problem is that the returned values contain parts such as "£" instead of £, etc. Is there a convenient way to simply convert all of these into the correct characters so that they can be displayed in a UILabel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you any further:
[HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

You maybe can use HTML entities to make your currency character.