# App not displaying 'á' properly in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why does my app draw 'á' as '&aacute' in a UILabel.

I parse the text off a webpage and then draw the text into a label.

Is there something I am missing?

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the data in the web page is HTML entity encoded so that `á` is expressed as`&aacute;`. However, as the UILabel doesn't parse/display HTML, it simply displays the content as-is.

As such, you'd need to entity decode the data (to convert `&aacute;` back to `á`) prior to displaying it. The existing [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch) question/answers (and other questions it links to) should be of some assistance.