# TBXML Parsing Bug while parsing &

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, parsing, tbxml

When I parse the below xml:

...
`<opp_brief> N & S nishu </opp_brief>`...

using the following line code:

```
TBXMLElement *element10 = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"opp_brief" parentElement:element8];
```

`if (element10 != nil)`
`{ NSLog(@"TBXMLLLLL::::: %@",[TBXML textForElement:element10]); }`

output of NSLog is:
`TBXMLLLLL::::: N &amp; S nishu`

I dont know from where "amp;" is coming with the &...

Can any one help....

Comment: '&amp;' is the '&' corresponding HTML entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBXML apparently doesn't offer any option to resolve that. Check out this question on SO : [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch).