# Problems with UTF-8 chars (iOS, NSString)

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, utf-8, nsstring

when I parse XML document I get strings like that: "ve&#269;inoma son&#269;no " How do I replace &#269; with correct values? Do I have to manually replace them one by one, or is there better way.

Thanks!

Comment: NSString *str = originalstring;
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"'"];

Answer (score 1):

They're HTML Entities, it's not to do with UTF-8. This question and it's answers might help you: [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)