# how to get text from JSON request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, encoding

I use the code below to retrieve a text data from the server in requestDidFinished method:

```
  NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
  NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
  if (responseDict != Nil) {            
      self.dataArray = [responseDict allValues];
      NSLog(@"data Array: %@",self.dataArray);
}
```

**Log:**

```
    data Array: (
    "Welcome To Let&rsquo;s Drive"
)
```

Now i need to know to to put the log message in textView and **how** to let the word "Let's" appear properly not `"Let&rsquo;s"`

Comment: Where are u getting this JSON data? Is it from your server?

Comment: @Satyamsvv yes http//www.....page.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the string through an HTML character decoder to get rid of the HTML entities.

Check out this question for more details on how to do it:
[HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Comment: 10q Kristofer I used the second answer from the link you put it in your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a string encoding problem, what does responseString come out as in an NSLog? You could specify the encoding by creating a string with response data

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

something like

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or whatever the expected encoding is.