# German Special Characters Problems

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, json, iphone-5

In the MySQl database, we have description that have special characters like "ä ö ü ß", i want to show  this characters in the iPhone, But we are some binary or others form of these characters.Please guide me how to show these character in PHP JSON Webservices and after in iPhone App.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416237/iphone-display-encoded-characters-like-a-a-o-in-uilabel

Comment: please use utf8_encode at php end