# How to remove '#038;' intelligently in WordPress url for programming in iPhone Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress, rss, feed

I'm developing a WordPress app for iPhone. I get links from feed.

The problem is links in xml is changed if it has '&' character. '&' is replaced by '&#038;'.

For example:

> http://localhost/web-wp/?feed=rss2&#038;p=1

I can correct this problem by the simple statement below:

```
link = [link stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#038;" withString:@"&"];
```

It run correctly, the result is

> http://localhost/web-wp/?feed=rss2&p=1

But I want a intelligent solution same as:

```
link =[link stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The above statement run incorrectly.

How can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking here. The first statement works correctly?

Comment: @danielbeard Sorry for my lack about information. I've edited my questions. Please check. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch  And check out Michael Waterfall's solution, although check the license restrictions