# objective c string encoding issue

Tags: iphone, encoding, nsstring, cjk

My app receives some data from server which is in XML format and some tags contains Japanese words. When I tried to execute the link in the browser, it gets the correct response in Japanese.  For example:

```
<root>
    <categorylist>
        <cid>19</cid>
        <cname>ファミリー</cname>
        <lang>jap</lang>
    </categorylist>
</root>
```

..but in my app, the response string is in some encoded format like the following:

```
<root>
    <categorylist>
        <cid>19</cid>
        <cname>&#x30D5;&#x30A1;&#x30DF;&#x30EA;&#x30FC;</cname>
        <lang>jap</lang>
    </categorylist>
</root>
```

My code to receive XML from the server is:

```
 NSString *req=@"http://www.myserver.com/category.php?lang=jap";    
    NSString *resultString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Is there a problem with my code?  How can I convert the response to correct Japanese strings?

Comment: Those are correctly encoded XML Unicode code points; those *are* correct Japanese strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at some of the decoding methods listed on this question: [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)