# Htmlcharacters in Textlabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have a UITableview, in the tableview i'm grabbing a JSON feed. But sometimes it's displaying htmlcharacters like `&#8220;` instead of `“` does anyone know how i can convert this in xcode?

Can i set a encoding for my textlabel?

```
[[cell textLabel]  setText:[item objectForKey:@"title" ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm fetching strings from a web server and if they're destined for any User Interface, I usually de-louse (errr, de-percent-escape them) via this "`NSString`" method:

[`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:) (documentation linked for you).

This gets rid of the URL encoded pieces of strings.

Now, as to the HTML characters like "`&#8220`", that requires an additional NSString category to do some work.

[And other people have already written this category for you.  Take a look at the various answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch) and one of them should work well.