# how to convert into NSString?

Tags: iphone

I am stuck with utf-8 to NSString. I am getting this data from web service :

```
{
    Description = "&#28450;&#23383;&#20206;&#21517;&#20132;&#12376;&#12426;&#25991;";
    Images =
    (
        {
            imageName = "0_25_07_2012_10_32_54_1343212374.jpg";
        }
    );
    Time = "11:00 am";
    actId = 290;
    actTitle = "&#28450;&#23383;&#20206;&#21517;&#20132;&#12376;&#12426;&#25991;";
}
```

Now how can i convert `&#21517;` (名) this kind of code to `NSString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with your web service. If the web service response is JSON or XML data, then the JSON or XML parser should have decoded the special characters. Since it did not, the web service mistakenly uses a double decoding of characters outside the ASCII range.

The best solution is to fix it at the source, i.e. in the web service.

If you can't, then use the `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities` method from this [NSString category](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m), e.g.:

```
NSString* textValue = [response objectForKey: @"Description"];
textValue = [textValue stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
```

You will have to run each string property through this method.

Answer (score 0):

The codes that you have here are called numeric character references. They have nothing directly to do with UTF8 in general.

[See this question for a summary of answers to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)