# iPhone - Convert text from ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, encoding

I'm getting text from a server, the text is encoded with `ISO 8859-1`. 
How can I convert it to UTF-8?

Now I'm just replacing special characters like this:

```
text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&Eacute;" withString:@"Ê"];
```

Comment: `&Eacute;` isn't an ISO 8859-1 character, it's an HTML entity.

Comment: See this prior thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/1105169/96716

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString* myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: theData 
                                           encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. 
Even if you get the `data` you received is formatted in ISO Latin string,

```
NSString* latin1String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

or if the text is NSString from latin1 string,

```
NSData *utfData = [latin1String dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *utf = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:utfData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is specially needed for NSJSONSerialization since it accept only utf8 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 2.2

If your string is HTML encoded:

```
func replaceChars(htmlEncodedString: String) -> String {
    do {
        let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
        ]
        let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
        return attributedString.string
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

If your string is ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) encoded:

```
func decodeISO88591(str:String) -> String {
   if let utfData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding) {
       if let utf = String(data: utfData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
           return utf
       }
    }
    return str
}
```