# how to get % from web-service in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios4, xml-parsing

I'm new in iPhone development.I'm developing one chatting application.i was facing problem while sending and receiving  some special character.finally, i succeeded to post and get this special character.now,there is only one special character which i'm not able to get it.while i'm sending % to the web-service,i get %25.

At sending string to web-serive use bellow string..

```
NSString *string = @"Hello % How Are You?";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%" withString:@"%25"];
NSLog(@"\n\n ===>> Before ==>> %@",string);
NSString *string2 = string;
string2 = [string2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%25" withString:@"%"];
NSLog(@"\n\n ===>> After ==>> %@",string2);
```

OutPut =>

```
===>> Before ==>> Hello%2520%2525%2520how%2520are%2520you?

 ===>> After ==>> Hello %2526 How Are You?
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code...

```
NSString *string = @"Hello % How Are You?";

string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
string = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
NSLog(@"\n\n ===>> Before ==>> %@",string);

NSString *string2 = string;

string2 = [string2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
string2 = [string2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%26" withString:@"&"];
string2 = [string2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%25" withString:@"%"];    
NSLog(@"\n\n ===>> After ==>> %@",string2);
```

**OUTPUT IS:**

```
===>> Before ==>> Hello%20%25%20How%20Are%20You?
====>> After ==>> Hello % How Are You?
```

Comment: Em still facing problem while sending smiley.what actually happen,if i send more than one smileys without giving any spece between two smileys.than i gt special character.can u help me?