# Remove HTML tags when Parsing an XML file in Xcode

Tags: html, ios, xml, parsing, tags

I'm developing an iPad app where I need to parse data from an XML file.

All data is being parsed except when it contains html tags like "&"

Do you know how I can parse html tags in an XML file?

Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) link. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch) is where I have found the solution.