# Apostrophe not recognized into NSString from json file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I try to get a value from a json file and restore it into an NSString but when the content contains apostrophe

**e.g.** de `l'Achéron`

i get this as **result**: de `l&#8217;Achéron`

I observed that this coding exists to json file too.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: source and result are the same in your example

Comment: I updated the post so the encoding is shown.

Comment: LOL e.g and result are the same, please review your example.

Comment: Show some more code including some log of the JSON string AS YOU RECEIVED IT.

Comment: Which parser you use? I mean NSJSONSerializer, JSONKit, etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Answer (score 1):

You need review you server code if you can, because before put the `l'Achéron` in json you need set it as UTF-8 with an enconde function.

in PHP it is made with: `$str_encoded=urlencode($str_utf8);`

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cause server coding is not under my responsibility this worked and fixed my problem.

```
NSString *lala=textfromJSON;
lala=[lala stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#8217;" withString:@"'"];
```

Comment: That helps with _one_ Unicode character. There are a bit over a million of them. If the server code is produced by your company, then tell them that people think they are incompetent. If it's not done by your company, could you tell us which service it is so have a warning?