# I want to remove static text from string - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, symbols, nsscanner

Hi I have a News Reader and I keep getting a string like this -

> `two New York police officers shot dead in &#039;ambush&#039;`

```
I want the string two New York police officers shot dead in ambush
```

How can I scan from & to ; and then delete occurrences of the scan.

I created a scanner like so -

```
NSString *webString222222 = filteredTitle2;
        NSScanner *stringScanner222222 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:webString222222];
        NSString *content222222 = [[NSString alloc] init];
        [stringScanner222222 scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:Nil];
        [stringScanner222222 scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&content222222];
        NSString *filteredTitle222 = [content222222 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:content222222 withString:@""];
        NSString *filteredTitle22 = [filteredTitle222 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@""];
```

But when I do this code the whole text disappears! Every single word.
When I check the title in my NSLog that is the only & sign in there and the only ; sign in there!
Im not sure where I went wrong here.

Comment: Why don't you just replace "&#039" with ""?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch).

Comment: Install documentation and read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSRegularExpression` to build proper matching pattern:

```
NSString *pattern = @"\\&#[0-9]+;";
NSString *str = @"two New York police officers shot dead in &#039;ambush&#039;";

NSLog(@"Original test: %@",str);
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"ERror: %@",error);
} 
else 
{
    NSString *replaced = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str
                                                         options:0
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])
                                                    withTemplate:@""];

    NSLog(@"Replaced test: %@",replaced);
}
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If the special characters you are encountering are all relatively consistent you can merely replace each of those substrings with the empty string, like so:

```
NSString *cleansedString = [filteredTitle2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#039;" 
                                                                     withString:@""];
```

Comment: What goes after the & and before the ; are completely different. IDK whats there!