# NSJSONSerializzation not reading UTF8 correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, utf-8

I'm reading a JSON from an URL. It is UTF8 formatted. When I load the UITableView It shows incorrect characters. 
Please find attached screenshot at row 2[image]

The code that reads the data is the following:

```
NSURL *myURL=[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://www.bancariromani.it/cecadm/newClass/modules/rh/index.php?id_cup=15&json=1"];

NSError *error;
NSData *myData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
if(!myData){

    return;

}

NSArray *jasonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

I've also tried this without luck:

```
NSURL *myURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bancariromani.it/cecadm/newClass/modules/rh/index.php?id_cup=15&json=1"];

 NSError *error;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:nil];

 NSData *myData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if(!myData){

    return;

}
NSArray *jasonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Where I'm i loosing the UTF8 format?

Thanks for helping me

Dario

Comment: Suggestion: Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for URL calls

Comment: Checking what that URL returns, it returns perfectly fine JSON not containing any URL-encoded characters. It looks very much like you are adding them yourself at some point between parsing the JSON data and putting the text into your table view.

Comment: Checking further, you didn't tell us that the JSON data contains URL's and you are downloading _those_ URLs, which don't contain any JSON whatsoever. So the problem that you have has nothing at all to do with JSON, and nothing at all to do with UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is using the HTML-way to store special characters. It is different from UTF-8 and is a way to add special characters using ASCII-codepoints.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3 for how they work. A way to decode them is answered in [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169).

Comment: Thanks, the link provided the solution I've used and tested!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "**&#039;**" part on second row? That's HTML and you can convert that by doing url encoding. You could try this method:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Comment: `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is for replacing things like `%20` to a space. It doesn't work for HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

That `&#039;` is the HTML-escape of a character; that's not related to UTF-8 at all.

Either ask your WebService to stop encoding HTML entities with their percent-escapes, as there is generally no need for them to do that… or you can use a method to remove them, like with this code:

```
NSMutableString* yourString = [… mutableCopy];
CFStringTransform((CFMutableStringRef)yourString, NULL, kCFStringTransformToXMLHex, true);
NSLog(@"transformed string: %@", yourString);
```

Unfortunately, this only seems to work for HTML-entities expressed as hexadecimal codepoints, like `&#x27;` and not the ones expressed as decimal codepoints, like `&#039`.

So here is a custom method to do just that (decoding decimal HTML-entities):

```
NSString* decodeHTMLEntities(NSString* string)
{
    NSRegularExpression* decimalEntity = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"&#(\\d+);" options:0 error:nil];
    NSMutableString* resultString = [string mutableCopy];
    NSInteger __block offset = 0;
    [decimalEntity enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length)
                                 usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
     {
         unsigned decimalCode = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]].intValue;
         NSString* decodedChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)decimalCode];
         result = [result resultByAdjustingRangesWithOffset:offset];
         [resultString replaceCharactersInRange:result.range withString:decodedChar];
         offset += (NSInteger)decodedChar.length - (NSInteger)result.range.length;
     }];
    return [resultString copy];
}
```

*(Of course it would be way better to ask your WebService provider to fix it at the source, as they have no valid reason to do that in the first place)*