# Objective-C convert &#263 to ć

Tags: objective-c

> when  coding ,i  have a problem  like this:

the  string   just like :@Krunoslav Margić

i wonder how to  convert &#263  to   ć  ?  i don't know what  Encoding can work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Comment: many tks.  i use  [NSString category for HTML](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) and it   did work