# iphone - how to remove the html encoded string from nsstring?

Tags: iphone, html, unicode, nsstring

I obtain some text from Internet. There are sometimes characters like "&a m p;", "&q u o t;", etc in teh text.

I guess they are some kind of unicode characters in Html. they are HTML encoded string, thanks for jason to point out.

How should I filter all these kinds of things out of the text? I don't want any HTML related code characters. by the way, I am not talking about the HTML tags in the text, only these kinds of unicode things.

thanks

Comment: sorry, i have to add spaces between a m p or so, otherwise, it won't show

Comment: They are not unicode, they are html encoded strings. &amp; is an ampersand (&), &quot; is a quotation mark ("), etc.

Comment: Thanksn Jason, then how can i use a unified method to remove them? in C#, there is a official method to remove them. but how can I find in objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered here:

[Converting &amp; to & in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067652/converting-to-in-objective-c)