# Remove HTML encoded characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, html-encode

Using **Objective-C**, how can I convert the `NSString`

```
@"Panda&#39;s Expenses"
```

into this string

```
@"Panda's Expenses"
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *reformedPanda =
    [@"Panda&#39;s Expenses" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: That's for percent escapes such as %20 for a space.

Comment: `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` would be most helpful here

Answer (score 2):

Check these two posts. Should solve your issue.

[HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

[Converting &amp; to & in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067652/converting-to-in-objective-c)