# How to get rid of &gt; &lt; (html tags) in woot.com API?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I am making a <a href="http"//www.woot.com">woot app, and I am using the [API](http://api.woot.com/1/sales/current.rss/www.woot.com). in the description section of the XML rss file, there are always a lot of `&gt;` and `&lt;` (less than and greater than < >) surrounding the html tags. I realize they did this so as not to confuse them with the XML tags, but it is kind of annoying. I can't just put the code that I get from the XML file right into a webview, because it displays the less than and greater than signs, and does not actually do the tags. Is there any way to get rid of this easily, or do I just have to make a loop that goes through all of the code, changing the `&lt;/tr&gt;` to `</tr>`? I am just wondering how other people have gotten around this problem, or if there is some easy way to do it that I just don't know about.

Comment: hi everyone so thank you for your responses i looked at them and i they are both good i am going to try them to see which one works but i might not have time so eventually i will give you a check for correct answer but it might be a day or two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is encoded and you just need to decode it--once you do that it should just render like regular html.  I would try to do that first before doing any kind of replace.  I'm not an iphone developer but maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067652/converting-amp-to-in-objective-c) can help.

Answer (score 1):

The xml rss file that you are looking at has HTML encoded inside of XML. All you need to do is use an existing XML library for the iPhone such as [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [GDataXML](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/) and you will not have to worry about decoding.