# How do I reliably convert special characters like £ to HTML equivalents using Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, email, html-entities, macos

I'm trying to feed Mail.app some simple html: lists, bold font, some italics. However, I noticed that if I use characters like `£`, then Mail.app just doesn't show anything. I realized I need to convert to HTML entities, like `&pound;` (full list here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp). I have a partial solution that works for most characters my users have come up with, but it's far from being a solid fix:

```
- (NSString*) makeValidHTML:(NSString*)str {
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"£" withString:@"&pound;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¢" withString:@"&cent;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¥" withString:@"&yen;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"©" withString:@"&copy;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"®" withString:@"&reg;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"°" withString:@"&deg;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¿" withString:@"&iquest;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¡" withString:@"&iexcl;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"‘" withString:@"'"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"'"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"“" withString:@"&quot;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
  str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];
  return str;
}
```

Is there a standard way to do this without having to list every possible reserved character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class should be helpful to you:
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m

Link retrieved from this other SO answer:
[Converting &amp; to & in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067652/converting-amp-to-in-objective-c/2843454#2843454)

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you're not encoding and declaring your HTML page as UTF-8. While some of the entities you mention are a genuine issue and need to be converted, such as `>` to `&gt;` (the code @Joel Martinez linked to will help there), things like the `£` symbol will work just fine as they are, provided the page is declared and encoded to be a unicode format such as UTF-8:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Tried this and it didn't make any difference, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This actually won't work when the server is sending out the charset in the Content-Type HTTP header, because HTTP headers have precedence over meta headers.