# converting the string by including backward slashes in front of "

Tags: iphone, replace

i want convert the follwing string

```
      &lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;314&#39;&#39; src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

into

```
      <iframe width=\"560\" height=\"314\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

thank you

Comment: Why you want that ? Explain the purpose behind conversion.

Comment: actually i want to play video in iphone and iam getting the url from the service

Comment: In that case, you should add the Service Response in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer :** [**MWFeedParser**](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m).

There are many methods as shown below. You can use them for your purpose.

1. `- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;`
2. `- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;`
3. `- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;`
4. `- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities:(BOOL)isUnicode;`
5. `- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;`
6. `- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;`

Credit goes to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843454/1603072).

Comment: still my vedio is not palying

Comment: @siva : Have you converted the String ? Are you getting the expected conversion result ? Have you used `NSLog` ?

Comment: NSString *videoLink=@"http://www.youtube.com/";
    NSString *myHTML =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                         <html>\
                         <head>\
                         <body>\
                         <iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                         </body>\
                         </html>",videoLink];

Comment: but i need like this to play video i think now u got my problem

Comment: [webView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];

Comment: @siva: What you asked is all about conversion. I solved your Problem. (For that you should Accept the Answer). Now regarding playing the Video, you should ask a new Question.

Comment: what i asked first only is the same thing placing slashes in front of "

Answer (score 0):

It should be done like :-

```
NSString *HtmlString = @"<iframe width="560" height="314' src="http://www.youtube.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

HtmlString = [HtmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@"\""] ;
```

Hope this helps .... Please view the edit...

Comment: sry i want to keep \ infront of "

Comment: You said you want to convert .... What is ur question exactly please edit accordingly...

Comment: menas i want to place a backward slash infront of all " like in the variables width height src

Comment: if i follwed like this iam getting error bcoz " is not accepting as a string  semicolon it self indicates that end of string

Comment: could u plz try above statement iam getting error   HtmlString = [HtmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@"\""