# I am parsing data from an rss feed from iOS and I am trying to convert &#36 to a currency symbol and use it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am grabbing data from a RSS feed dictionary and seems to be working, but the problem is it parses the symbol instead of actual currency. I am not sure what is the best way to go about this. Here is a tiny snippet of the code. I know there is NSLocale, but not sure if that is the best way to do this.

```
     [currencyDict valueForKey:@"currency_symbol"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of Currency symbols here: http://www.forex-rates.biz/currency-symbols.htm

and use below code to Replace them.

```
yourstring= [yourstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#36" withString:@"$"];
```

You can get a similar [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067652/converting-amp-to-in-objective-c).