# Restkit AFNetworking response is not proper

Tags: ios, afnetworking, restkit

I'm calling an API and receiving a response in Spanish. In the Browser it looks OK, but when I call it in the app, it shows weird characters.

For example, in the browser I see `Automóvil`, but in the app I see `Autom&oacute;vil`.

I'm using RestKit:

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",@"charset=UTF-8", nil]];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

manager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[manager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[manager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[manager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept-Encoding" value:@"gzip, deflate"];`
```

Comment: Those are [HTML character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML). There's bound to be a decoding method for that on your platform.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067652/converting-amp-to-in-objective-c

Comment: How are you testing it in the app?

Comment: [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient
     getPath:@"api.php"
     parameters:param
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     }];
}

Comment: I'm calling it in above way

Comment: I don't want to HTML encode and decode every time, I'm sure there will be a way out to get response in proper form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you're receiving is encoded with HTML entities (also called "character entity references"). For example, `&oacute;` represents `ó` because of the acute accent over the o.

Ideally, you'd have an API that would just send you everything in UTF-8, but if that's not possible, you'll need to decode the text yourself. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1105169/1445366) provides a number of solutions.

Comment: If you only need to support iOS 7 and above, I would try [this approach first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901056/1445366).